# How to prove that the expectation of Cox Ingersoll Ross interest rate model is $r_0e^{-at} + b(1-e^{-at})$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

The [Cox Ingersoll Ross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cox%E2%80%93Ingersoll%E2%80%93Ross_model#:%7E:text=In%20mathematical%20finance%2C%20the%20Cox,valuation%20of%20interest%20rate%20derivatives.) is given in the form:

$$dr_t = a(b-r_t)dt + \sigma \sqrt{r_t}dW_t$$

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cox%E2%80%93Ingersoll%E2%80%93Ross_model#:%7E:text=In%20mathematical%20finance%2C%20the%20Cox,valuation%20of%20interest%20rate%20derivatives.), the expected value of it i.e $E[r_t|r_0]$ is

$$r_0e^{-at} + b(1-e^{-at})$$

but I don't really understand how it's derived. Can you give some hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Remark that

$$\mathbb E[r_t]=\mathbb E[r_0]-a \int_0^t\mathbb E[r_s]\,\mathrm ds+abt$$

and use [Gronwall inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality#Integral_form_for_continuous_functions).

Comment: It's clear for me how to obtain $\mathbb E[r_t]=\int_0^t\mathbb E[r_s]\,\mathrm ds+abt$ using Ito's Lemma, however, it's not clear what inequality can give me apart from some bound

Comment: UPD: I got it. Thank you.

Comment: @student: No Itô Lemma is used here.

Comment: @Surb I think that you have used $E[ \int_0^t \sqrt{r_s} dW_s ] = 0$. How can you obtain it? Since $r_s$ depends on $\omega$, it does not seem to me that it immediately follows.

Comment: @KazuneTakahashi: A solution of such SDE is s.t. $\mathbb E\int_0^tr_s^2ds<\infty $ for all $t>0$. Therefore is $L^1(\Omega \times [0,t])$ as well...

Comment: @Surb Thanks for your comment. But I am still wondering why $r_t \in L^1(\Omega \times [0, t])$ is important for obtaining your hint. Do you apply a famous proposition here?

Comment: @Surb Are you saying as follows? You know that $E[\int_0^t r_s^2 ds] < \infty$ by some means and thus $\{ \sqrt{r_t} \}_{t \in [0, T]} \in \mathcal{L_2}$. Hence we have $\{ \int_0^t \sqrt{r_s} dW_s \}_{t \in [0, T]}$ is a (continuous square-integrable) martingale. Therefore $E[\int_0^t \sqrt{r_s} dW_s] = E[0] = 0$.

Comment: @KazuneTakahashi: yes.